# How to prevent styled-components from stripping custom HTML attributes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, styled-components

My project is trying to switch to styled-components, but there is one big issue: our automated QA tests rely on a custom attribute called `qa-component` appearing in the dom for each HTML element that it is defined for.

The old way we did this worked fine: `<div style={ styles.cssModuleStyle } qa-component="big-area" />` would translate to the dom as `<div class="whatever" qa-component="big-area" />`.

However, when using styled components, the `qa-component` attribute gets stripped because SC thinks its a prop.

How can I get styled-components to pass this custom attribute to the dom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `withConfig` + `shouldForwardProp`. It allows you to define what props get passed down. Here's how you can implement the desired behavior:

```
const StyledTitle = styled.h1.withConfig({
  shouldForwardProp: (prop, defaultValidatorFn) =>
    defaultValidatorFn(prop) || ['qa-attribute'].includes(prop),
})`
  text-decoration: underline;
`;
```

Take a look at the docs here: https://styled-components.com/docs/api#shouldforwardprop

And here's a playground with this approach: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-71912300

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to apply this globally?

Comment: `styled-components` doesn't provide a way to configure this globally as far as I know. The only way I can think of is to create a base component and extend it whenever you need a custom `shouldForwardProp`. I updated the playground with this example.